# MySQL subquery for values in ORDER BY FIELD

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to write a query which will get the maximum scores for the most popular songs, in order of song popularity.

I have a table called "gameplay" with the following fields:

- id
- song_id
- score
- (plus some other arbitrary fields)

So far, the closest I've got is this:

```
SELECT id, song_id, score
FROM (
    SELECT id, song_id, score
    FROM (
        SELECT id, song_id, score
        FROM gameplay
        ORDER BY score DESC
        ) AS all_scores_in_order
    GROUP BY song_id
    ) AS top_scores_per_song
ORDER BY FIELD (song_id, 3,1,2)
```

But I would like the values in `ORDER BY FIELD` to be generated by another subquery - the song_id ranked by popularity (in order of counting row occurrences in table) ie.

```
SELECT song_id
FROM gameplay
GROUP BY song_id
ORDER BY count( id ) DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just group and then order by Count(id) in the outer query?

This should show all sorts sorted by the number of occurrences, and showing the max score:

```
SELECT song_id, COUNT(id), MAX(score)
FROM gameplay
GROUP BY song_id
ORDER count(id) DESC
```

Or do you want each song_id to appear several times?

Comment: I've clearly been over-thinking this, I didn't realise SELECT MAX(score) would select the max score from each grouping as opposed to selecting only the max of the whole table! Thanks Cylindric :)

Comment: Oh, I've built some beautiful huge queries that ended up being replaced with a simple one-liner GROUP or some tricky OVER clause that I missed :)